# Pagination for a table in yii

Tags: php, yii, pagination

I'm using Yii application. In that how to give pagination to a table contents( not using cgridview).

**config/main.php**

```
'params'=>array(
    'adminEmail'=>'webmaster@example.com',
    'listPerPage'=> 10,//default pagination size
),
```

**In Controller,**

```
  public function actionOutbox() {
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->condition = 'from_userid = :id';
    $criteria->order = 'time DESC';
    $criteria->params = array (':id'=>Yii::app()->user->id);

    $item_count = Email::model()->count($criteria);
    $model      = Email::model()->findAll($criteria);

    $pages = new CPagination($item_count);
    $pages->setPageSize(Yii::app()->params['listPerPage']);
    $pages->applyLimit($criteria);

    $this->render('outbox', array(
        'model' => $model,
        'item_count'=>$item_count,
        'page_size'=>Yii::app()->params['listPerPage'],
        'items_count'=>$item_count,
        'pages'=>$pages,
    ));
}
```

**In View,**

```
 <table data-provides="rowlink" data-page-size="20" data-filter="#mailbox_search" class="table toggle-square default footable-loaded footable" id="mailbox_table">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th></th>
                                    <th data-hide="phone,tablet">To</th>
                                    <th>Subject</th>
                                    <th data-hide="phone" class="footable-last-column">Date</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <?php
                                foreach ($model as $item) {
                                    if ($item->email_status == 1)
                                        echo '<tr id="' . $item->emailid . '" class="unreaded rowlink" style="display: table-row;">';
                                    else
                                        echo '<tr id="' . $item->emailid . '" class="rowlink" style="display: table-row;">';
                                    echo '<td class="nolink footable-first-column">';
                                    echo '<span class="footable-toggle"></span>';

                                    echo '</span></td>';
                                    echo '<td>' . $item->touser->username . '</td>';
                                    echo '<td>' . $item->email_subject . '</td>';
                                    $originalDate = $item->time;
                                    $newDate = date("Y-M-d H:i:s", strtotime($originalDate));


                                    echo '<td class="footable-last-column">' . $newDate . '</td></tr>';
                                }
                                ?>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
<?php
  $this->widget('CLinkPager', array(
        'currentPage' => $pages->getCurrentPage(),
        'itemCount' => $item_count,
        'pageSize'=> $page_size,
        'maxButtonCount' => 5,
        //'nextPageLabel' =>'My text >',
        'htmlOptions' => array('class'=>'pages'),
    ));
     ?>
```

By using this code current page size is not working. Full values from table are displayed. I changed page size from 10 to 2 also, but not working.

What am I doing wrong?

Please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [pagination for a table contents in yii](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32523304/pagination-for-a-table-contents-in-yii)

Answer (score 1):

You use `findAll` without limit and want that yii understand about pagination?

Use [CGridView](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView) widget instead it and set pagination in [DataProvider](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDataProvider) (not create separate object of pagination: **it not affort to result count**).

And please read [this topic](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/381/cgridview-clistview-and-cactivedataprovider/).

Thanks.